# How to use following-sibling to click in all <li> inside <ul JAVA

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, xpath

I can click on "Mentorship" li tag but I want to click on every li, starting from the "Mentorship" tag link

```
<ul _ngcontent-cwp-c18="" class="navigation clearfix">
   <li _ngcontent-cwp-c18="" routerlinkactive="current" class=""><a _ngcontent-cwp-c18="" href="#/index">Home</a></li>
   <li _ngcontent-cwp-c18=""><a _ngcontent-cwp-c18="" href="https://courses.rahulshettyacademy.com/courses">Courses</a></li>
   <li _ngcontent-cwp-c18="" routerlinkactive="current" class="current"><a _ngcontent-cwp-c18="" href="#/mentorship">Mentorship</a></li>
   <li _ngcontent-cwp-c18="" routerlinkactive="current"><a _ngcontent-cwp-c18="" href="#/practice-project">Practice Projects</a></li>
   <li _ngcontent-cwp-c18="" routerlinkactive="current"><a _ngcontent-cwp-c18="" href="#/consulting">Consulting</a></li>
   <li _ngcontent-cwp-c18="" routerlinkactive="current"><a _ngcontent-cwp-c18="" href="#/part-time-jobs">Earn</a></li>
   <li _ngcontent-cwp-c18=""><a _ngcontent-cwp-c18="" href="http://www.qaclickacademy.com/blog/">Articles</a></li>
   <li _ngcontent-cwp-c18="" routerlinkactive="current"><a _ngcontent-cwp-c18="" href="#/about-my-mission">About</a></li>
   <li _ngcontent-cwp-c18="" routerlinkactive="current"><a _ngcontent-cwp-c18="" href="#/contact-us">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is what I Tried:

```
driver.get("http://www.qaclickacademy.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right']//a[contains(text(),'Interview Guide')]")).click();
        //mentorship
        driver.findElementByXPath("//div[@class='nav-outer clearfix']//a[contains(text(),'Mentorship')]").click();
        //practice projects
        driver.findElementByXPath("//div[@class='nav-outer clearfix']//a[contains(text(),'Mentorship')]/following-sibling::li[1]").click();
        //consulting
        driver.findElementByXPath("//div[@class='nav-outer clearfix']//a[contains(text(),'Mentorship')]/following-sibling::li[2]").click();
        //earn
        driver.findElementByXPath("//div[@class='nav-outer clearfix']//a[contains(text(),'Mentorship')]/following-sibling::li[3]").click();
```

Please, how do I use following-siblings to click in every line, starting from a specific one?

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the parent (..) of the `a` element before using `following-sibling`. You can use :

```
//div[@class='nav-outer clearfix']//a[contains(text(),'Mentorship')]/../following-sibling::li[1]/a
//div[@class='nav-outer clearfix']//a[contains(text(),'Mentorship')]/../following-sibling::li[2]/a
//div[@class='nav-outer clearfix']//a[contains(text(),'Mentorship')]/../following-sibling::li[3]/a
```

Or, shorter but more consuming form :

```
//div[@class='nav-outer clearfix']//a[contains(text(),'Mentorship')]/following::a[1]
//div[@class='nav-outer clearfix']//a[contains(text(),'Mentorship')]/following::a[2]
//div[@class='nav-outer clearfix']//a[contains(text(),'Mentorship')]/following::a[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to find the count of list which follows the li of `Mentorship` then you can iterate to click one after another. Write the following code, it works fine.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.navigate().to("http://www.qaclickacademy.com");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right']/li/a[contains(text(),'Interview Guide')]")).click();
int count = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='nav-outer clearfix']//li[a[contains(text(),'Mentorship')]]/following-sibling::li")).size();
for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='nav-outer clearfix']//li[a[contains(text(),'Mentorship')]]/following-sibling::li[" + i + "]")).click();
}
```